# Scrapes Emails from a list of URLs saved in CSV - BeautifulSoup

Tags: for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse thru a list of URLs saved in CSV format to scrape email addresses. However, the below code only managed to fetch email addresses from a single website. Need advice on how to modify the code to loop thru the list and save the outcome (the list of emails) to csv file.

```
import requests
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

allLinks = [];mails=[]
with open(r'url.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    urls = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    links = []
    for url in urls:
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
        links = [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('a[href]') ]

allLinks=set(links)

def findMails(soup):
    for name in soup.find_all('a'):
        if(name is not None):
            emailText=name.text
            match=bool(re.match('[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$',emailText))
            if('@' in emailText and match==True):
                emailText=emailText.replace(" ",'').replace('\r','')
                emailText=emailText.replace('\n','').replace('\t','')
                if(len(mails)==0)or(emailText not in mails):
                    print(emailText)
                mails.append(emailText)
for link in allLinks:
    if(link.startswith("http") or link.startswith("www")):
        r=requests.get(link)
        data=r.text
        soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
        findMails(soup)

    else:
        newurl=url+link
        r=requests.get(newurl)
        data=r.text
        soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
        findMails(soup)

mails=set(mails)
if(len(mails)==0):
    print("NO MAILS FOUND")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `links` when you want to add to it.

```
allLinks = [];mails=[]
urls = ['https://www.nus.edu.sg/', 'http://gwiconsulting.com/']
links = []

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
    links += [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('a[href]') ]

allLinks=set(links)
```

At end loop your mails and write to csv

```
import csv

with open("emails.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as csv_file:
    w = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    w.writerow(['Email'])
    for mail in mails:
        w.writerow(mail)
```

Comment: Have modified the script according to yours but only the second url (http://gwiconsulting.com/) gets initiated, not the first one

Comment: the nus link produces _www.nus.edu.sg - SSL Connection failed_  SSL is not supported   Check whether you are actually able to connect to the site and with raise_for_status() we get _HTTPError: 503 Server Error: Service Unavailable for url: https://www.nus.edu.sg/_

Comment: I have a list of 70 urls and some are invalid, is there a way to ignore those invalid urls and continue looping the valid ones and return the results?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

mails = set()

def findMails(soup):
    for name in soup.find_all('a'):
        if(name is not None):
            emailText = name.text
            match = bool(re.match('[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$', emailText))
            if('@' in emailText and match == True):
                emailText = emailText.replace(" ", '').replace('\r', '')
                emailText = emailText.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '')
                if len(mails) == 0 or emailText not in mails:
                    print(emailText)
                mails.add(emailText)

with open('emails.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    with open('url.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
        urls = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

        for url in urls:
            response = requests.get(url[0])
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
            links = [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('a[href]')]
            allLinks = set(links)

            for link in allLinks:
                if link.startswith("http") or link.startswith("www"):
                    r = requests.get(link)
                    data = r.text
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
                    findMails(soup)

                else:
                    newurl = url[0] + link
                    r = requests.get(newurl)
                    data = r.text
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
                    findMails(soup)

        if len(mails) == 0:
            print("NO MAILS FOUND")
        else:
            for email in mails:
                writer.writerow([email])
```

Comment: Would be great if you could edit your question and also improve it with some more details please.