# For Loop for scraping emails for mulitple urls - BS

Tags: for-loop, beautifulsoup

Below is the code for scraping emails for a single base url and I have been cracking my head on getting a simple "for loop" to do it for an array of urls or reading a list of urls (csv) into python. Can anyone modify the code so that it will do the job?

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

allLinks = [];mails=[]
url = 'https://www.smu.edu.sg/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
links = [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('a[href]') ]

allLinks=set(links)
def findMails(soup):
    for name in soup.find_all('a'):
        if(name is not None):
            emailText=name.text
            match=bool(re.match('[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$',emailText))
            if('@' in emailText and match==True):
                emailText=emailText.replace(" ",'').replace('\r','')
                emailText=emailText.replace('\n','').replace('\t','')
                if(len(mails)==0)or(emailText not in mails):
                    print(emailText)
                mails.append(emailText)
for link in allLinks:
    if(link.startswith("http") or link.startswith("www")):
        r=requests.get(link)
        data=r.text
        soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
        findMails(soup)

    else:
        newurl=url+link
        r=requests.get(newurl)
        data=r.text
        soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
        findMails(soup)

mails=set(mails)
if(len(mails)==0):
    print("NO MAILS FOUND")
```

Comment: Where is an error?

Comment: Didn't I answer basically [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58058619/scrapes-emails-from-a-list-of-urls-saved-in-csv-beautifulsoup/58061135#58061135) yesterday?